# Counting number of requests per second with embedded Jetty

Tags: embedded-jetty

I have an embedded Jetty server and I would like to know the number of requests per second it is currently serving.

Is there a way to get this number from Jetty?  Or even a total request count that I can periodically query and calculate my RPS on my own?

Comment: The statistics handler should work here shouldn't it? -http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/statistics-handler.html

Comment: @Colwin, I didn't know that existed.  Thanks!

Comment: :) Glad I could help!

Comment: Expanded my comment to an answer with relevant sections pulled from the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is present in the Statistics handler.

The handler allows to levels of collection on request statistics

1. Collect statistics about connections and number of requests from subclasses of `AbstractConnector`
2. StatisticsHandler to collect request statistics

Session statistics can be collected via subclasses of SessionHandler and DefaultSessionCache

AbstractConnector, SessionHandler and DefaultSessionCache statistics are turned off by default and must either be configured manually for each instance or turned on via JMX interface.

The StatisticsHandler is not included in default Jetty configuration, and needs to be configured manually.

You can turn on the collection using the configuration below in Jetty xml

```
<Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
        <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
        <Arg name="factories">
          <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
            <Item>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
                <Arg name="config"><Ref refid="httpConfig" /></Arg>
              </New>
            </Item>
          </Array>
        </Arg>
        <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.http.port" default="8080" /></Set>
        <Set name="idleTimeout">30000</Set>
        <!-- Enable Connection Statistics -->
        <Call name="addBean">
          <Arg>
              <New id="ConnectionStatistics" class="org.eclipse.jetty.io.ConnectionStatistics"/>
          </Arg>
        </Call>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
```

[Documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/statistics-handler.html)